# Создать C# класс из командной строки

Tags: dotnet-cli

Как добавить в проект новый файл с классом из командной строки в .NET Core?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
touch myclass.cs
```

И прописать в этом файле

```
namespace myproject.mynamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

Если в других файлах указать `using myproject.mynamespace;`, должно работать.

Answer (score 0):

Средствами `dotnet cli` увы, никак. Нет такой возможности.

Для этого воспользуйтесь расширением [C# Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jchannon.csharpextensions)